# Integration I'm confused how to start solving?

Tags: calculus, integration

Please help me with it 
$$\int \frac{x+2}{(x^2+3x+3)\sqrt{x+1}}dx$$

Comment: I tried removing the root from the bottom but that just made denominator nastier  I also tried to split numerator as x+1 +1 but to no avail.

Comment: The answer's horrible enough that this won't be an easy problem: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%2B2)%2F((x%5E2%2B3x%2B3)*(x%2B1)%5E(1%2F2))

Comment: I would try @AnuragA's method now then

Comment: also it would actually look like this in wolfram: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=integrate+(x%2B2)%2F((x%5E2%2B3x%2B3)sqrt(x%2B1))

Comment: What factorization, @Henry Lee ?

Comment: What you replying to @amWhy

Comment: @AnuragA $x^2 + 3x + 3$ is irreducible.  You can make the substitution, but partial fractions are not going to work.

Comment: @DougM You are right. I missed it when I suggested the hint. Thanks. So I have given an alternate approach.

Answer (score 2):

Let $x=t^2-1$, then $dx=2t\,dt$. The integral becomes
$$\int \frac{x+2}{(x^2+3x+3)\sqrt{x+1}}dx=2\int\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+t^2+1} \, dt=2\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{t^2+\frac{1}{t^2}+1} \, dt=2\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+3} \, dt$$
Now use $y=t-\frac{1}{t}$ as your substitution to get
$$2\int\frac{1+\frac{1}{t^2}}{\left(t-\frac{1}{t}\right)^2+3} \, dt=2\int\frac{1}{y^2+3} \, dy=\frac{2}{\sqrt{3}}\tan^{-1}\left(\frac{y}{\sqrt{3}}\right)+c,$$
where $y=\frac{t^2-1}{t}=\frac{x}{\sqrt{x+1}}$

Comment: Gotcha man thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

using the suggestion of $$x+1=t^2$$
you can achieve:
$$I=2\int\frac{t^2+1}{t^4+t^2+1}dt$$

Comment: oh yes because it is $\sqrt{x+1}$